# sshfs passwordless

Tags: sshfs

Does any one know ssh -i equivalent for sshfs ? I want to use sshfs without promting for a password

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best solution would be **`ssh-agent`** as Zoredache suggests.

Another is to put your key in **`~/.ssh/id_rsa`**, that way it will be detected automatically. (Use `id_dsa` for DSA keys.)

Yet another is **`~/.ssh/config`**. Put something like this in it (see manual page of `ssh_config` for further details)

```
Host somebox.somedomain.tld
  User joe
  IdentityFile ~/key_for_somebox

Host *
  IdentityFile ~/key_for_everything_else
```

Comment: I discovered the awesome usefulness of the ssh config file not too long ago.  It is very useful for multiple key setups.

Comment: Note that if you must `sudo sshfs` then `root` can't see your home `~/.ssh/id_rsa`

Answer (score 2):

Setup your system to use the [SSH Agent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ssh-agent) and add your key to the agent.  If you are using a recent Linux distro (ie Ubuntu and others) ssh-agent may already be setup for you.  All you have to do type `ssh-add key`.

Answer (score 1):

Another answer is `sshfs -o IdentityFile=/home/me/.ssh/somekey.pem user@host:/path/ mnt/`

Additionally, you will see people list another means of evoking sshfs:

`sshfs -o ssh_command="ssh -i /home/me/.ssh/somekey.pem" user@host:/path/ mnt/`

Though I will agree that `~/.ssh/config` is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite what you asked for, but for the benefit of anyone else trying to connect to a server that doesn't support key authentication, you can use `sshpass` to type in your password for you even with `sshfs`.

For example, if you put something similar to this in `/etc/fstab`:

```
sshfs#username@host:/  /mnt/here   fuse   auto,ssh_command=sshpass\040-f\040/root/.ssh/host.password\040ssh  0  0
```

Then put the password in the filename specified in `/etc/fstab`:

```
echo 'secret' > /root/.ssh/host.password
```

Make sure you have installed `sshpass`:

```
pacman -S sshpass  # if you're using Arch Linux
```

Then it should work:

```
mount /mnt/here
```

You might need to `ssh` to the server once first to confirm its key, but after that this should work with no manual interaction.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for this in the future this worked for me ::

```
sshfs username@host:/yourpath  /yourpath  -o ssh_command='sshpass -p "yourpassword" ssh'
```

Example::

```
sshfs root@192.168.1.1:/media /mnt/ -o ssh_command='sshpass -p 123456789 ssh'
```

Comment: Be warned that your password is now visible in whatever file you save this to.